# Color, size, stock Ecommerce CMS

Tags: php, cms, ecommerce, looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

Is there any cms written in php have support for managing color, size & stock of item.

and also if possible image of the product base on color?

Comment: Magento might do what you're looking to do

Comment: Agreed, Magento does nearly everything

Comment: can u give me more clear direction how to archive this? what plugin? or already contain at default installation?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/ - install and give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that prestashop already give feature without any plugin. and have a perfect way to implement those requiremen

Answer (score 0):

It is standard on magento, no plugins or modules needed.  Each variation is saved as a separate non-visable product with a main configurable product that groups them together.  Stock is tracked for each individual non-visible product.

Here's a [screencast](http://www.magentocommerce.com/media/screencasts/configurable-products/view) that shows it in action.